# Create migrations for diff between db and model definitions, without using previous migration history

Tags: django

I'd like to create a new instance of my application with a clean migration history from a backup copy of the database. The idea is that I get migrations which cover the difference in model definitions between what's in the database, and the model definitions for the branch of the application repository I'm testing out.

To be clear, I don't have an existing set of `py` migration files that match the database migration history, hence my desire to blow it all away and then just generate migrations for this particular branch.

I can drop the various application rows from the `django_migrations` table and delete the migration `py` files, but getting `manage.py` to generate some sort of `CREATE TABLE (or column) IF NOT EXISTS` is proving harder.

Is there an automated way to do this, or must I manually create the migration files?

I'm using django 1.11.2, postgres 9.5

Comment: You could try using `inspectdb` to generate models based on the current database, and make migrations based on them. Then switch back to your current models, and make migrations again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the easiest way to do it is manually inspect the model definitions, and their database representations, and then fake the initial migrations and manually create the new migrations where the model differs from the db:

```
$ manage.py inspectdb myapp_mymodel
$manage.py makemigrations myapp
$ # edit the migrations file to ensure it matches your db
$ manage.py migrate --fake myapp
$ # create a manual migration file to apply the changes
$ manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp
$ # edit the resulting file to add/remove fields as per the docs
$ # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#addfield
```